# How to set context-registry-service:read-only for a spa application?

Tags: bentley-itwin

I have a bridge application test harness which queries the api using GET /contextregistry/v2.5/Repositories/BentleyCONNECT--Main/ConnectedContext/Project?$select=*&$filter=Name+eq+%27Bentley-FutureOn%20Connector%20Handover%27

This is failing with the error "Authorization scheme is not supported".

I believe that this is caused by a change I made to the scopes defined for my spa application.
I believe that I need to add the context-registry-service:read-only to the scopes. However the Apps portal (https://developer.bentley.com/my-apps) no longer seems to be able to add this scope.

Answer (score 0):

`context-registry-service:read-only` scope, along with some others, was deprecated and replaced with a single `itwinjs` scope that you can allow by selecting 'Visualization' API group.

Existing applications that had deprecated scopes will continue working, but new applications must use the new `itwinjs` scope.